# Dynamically choose between redirecting to file and piping to a process

Tags: pipe, sh, posix

Suppose a shell script with the general form

```
(
    # ... lots of code here
) > logfile 2>&1
```

There is a feature request to optionally have the logs dumped to the terminal as well as the file, which would be written

```
(
    # ... lots of code here
) 2>&1 | tee logfile
```

The *question* is, how do I switch between these two pipeline constructs based on the value of a shell variable?  Ideally without requiring a `cat` process, or anything like that, in the case where the logs are not going to the terminal, for efficiency.

It is a hard requirement to use POSIX shell features only.  Also, due to bugs in older versions of zsh, the code inside the parentheses cannot be moved into a shell function.

Answer (score 2):

My take would be

```
(
   # ... lots of code here
) 2>&1 |
if test "$want_terminal_output" = yes; then
   tee logfile
else
   cat > logfile
fi
```

Yes, there's a (useful!) `cat`. Is efficiency of a single program really critical? I can see why anyone would consider it unaesthetic. If it hurts your eyes, write a read/write loop in the shell and profile it. Of course you can always duplicate `lots of code` and avoid the `cat` with the cut-n-paste way of programming so popular in this day and age :-)

Comment: I knew you could pipe to a while loop, but somehow it never occurred to me to try piping to an if-then-else.

Comment: @zwol I once wrote a script that piped into a `case` to generate different output formats (think ps, dvi, pdf, tiff). Control structures don't consume stdin, so all of them are available.

Answer (score 0):

Using `cat` shouldn't be a problem, but if it is:

`switcher.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

if $TERMINAL; then
    OUTFILE=/dev/tty
else
    OUTFILE=/dev/null
fi

(
    echo hello
) | tee logfile > $OUTFILE

echo "## log file ##"
cat logfile
```

```
$ TERMINAL=false ./switcher.sh 
## log file ##
hello
$ TERMINAL=true ./switcher.sh 
hello
## log file ##
hello
```

The implementation of `tee` and `/dev/null` is such that there won't be extra buffer copies.